Using a mesh to "Cull" a set of rigid body objects without affecting the physics simulation
I would like to create the effect of a small box that has a large amount of objects animating out from it.
Final project will have all the objects as rigid bodies being pushed out from a rigid body container (shown as the red block in the animated gif)

Desired Outcome




I have a container that is housing all the objects in side of it, then I animated the balls coming out.
The Final project will be done using rigid bodies hence why I have a container, the balls will be rigid body presents and then I use a plunger to push all the presents out of the box, Balls are just representing a proxy for various meshes
The issue I am having is that I cant find the correct way of using the container as a sort of "HOLDOUT" to hide the balls but still allowing geometry behind the container and balls to come through.
In a simple example as per the attached file I would usually just composite a clean plate, but the project I am working on has complex camera moves, environment and characters, so finding a solution inside of Blender is extreamly important.

I have attempted using a Light Path - Transparent Depth node in the shader editor without luck

I have tried turning it into a shadow catcher and turning off its shadow visibility also with no luck




Is there any particular reason why it has to be the complete number of objects? Are those all exactly the same like in the screenshots or varying ones? Is the camera view fixed or moving? I ask because people often show a simplified version of what they actually want and when you provide a solution they say, "well the real scene is a bit more complex..."

Hi Gordan, I have just simplified the entire file down to solve the specific issue I would like to solve, the final project is a scene with a moving camera, multiple shaped rigid body meshes and a rigid body container that I use to constrain the object inside of, then I animate a plunger to move all the object out of the box,
Heres an example of something similar, imagine a Uber food delivery motorcycle arriving at a location, they open up the box container in the back and an endless amount of food delivery packages stream out

You see, it's good to know that and posting that in the question because now I can throw my particle solution into the trash and do not have to work it out further.

Will update the heading to be more descriptive thanks for the feedback Gordon

You could use a Boolean modifier on your objects:


Thanks Moonboots, I was thinking about a boolean solution, in essence culling the objects within a specified mesh,
However I just need to confirm that the rigid body physics would still function, and that it wont do a "POP IN" explode due to the mesh verts changing

It may not work well with some meshes but we don't know how they look like. You could also try with the Compositor, it all depends on the storyboard

@MeestarP The rigid body physics will not work if you remove the geometry of the active rigid bodies with a Boolean modifier. For that you first have to bake the simulation into keyframes and then use a Boolean modifier on them. But of course you cannot change change the simulation anymore then.

it should work with physics, here is a try: https://i.postimg.cc/sfJMHf1h/anim.gif of course the boolean could not work fine with some topologies

@moonboots That's just one rigid body falling down with gravity. As I understood the explanations in the comments under the question, he wants to push objects out of the box with rigid body physics and interacting with each other... good luck with it when the object meshes to be pushed out are deleted by the modifier at first... The problem is, when the meshes are deleted/hidden by the modifier, then the rigid bodies will not show the meshes coming out of the box. At least not in my Blender. The objects behave as if they had meshes, but they are not visible.

This is how it looks in my Blender without removing the spheres with a Boolean modifier (I have x-ray enabled to show what's going on inside: spheres getting pushed out. And this is what it looks like if I remove the spheres with the modifier... all spheres except for the first one which was not within the culling object and a remaining slice of the second sphere are visible, the rest of them just show the origins but behave as if the spheres were there: spheres not visible.

Okay, now I'm interested in your file and/or Blender version... I have no idea what kind of magic you are doing there :D I tried the same simple setup: an icosphere falling through a cube. I have three versions, at the start one sphere is above the cube, fully visible, the second is half inside the cube and only half visible, the third sphere is inside the cube and completely invisible. All spheres fall down and remain in exact the same visibility state which they have from the start. How is yours disappearing and reappearing? three variations

here is my version, have enabled Rigid Body > Source > Base? 

Sorry, did not see your comment earlier because I wasn't tagged... ah okay, I see. At first I had the Collision Shape set to Sphere for simplicity, there you don't have a Source setting. But I switched to Convex Hull because the OP said it would be "multiple shaped rigid body meshes", and left the default Deform option. Turns out now of all options, the default one is the only one where it does not work  Setting Source to Final works as well... //EDIT: It did work with final, now after switching back and forth it doesn't work anymore, only in Base mode... weird.
